# Can't install Rails on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ruby, rails, ruby-on-rails

i'm noob.
This is my problem when i try.

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-1.2.1/ext/nio4r
```

/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20160630-19108-12sbtb7.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-1.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.3.0/nio4r-1.2.1/gem_make.out

Comment: What commands did you use to try to install Rails?

Answer (score 18):

I needed to install ruby-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
```

Cf: [This question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38822133/ruby-on-rails-fails-on-fresh-ubuntu-mint-and-fedora-because-of-debug-inspector). It recommends `sudo apt-get install build-essential patch` first, but my system didn't need that.

Comment: Simply `sudo apt install ruby-dev` did it for me on 17.10